# facing not found error and can't detect error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to create a page in my laravel app. When I create a route, controller in gave not found error. i recheck my code and again i can't detect my problem. In the below, i gave my view, controller and route code. please, anyone, help me i can't detect my problem.

View:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('brand.recycle') }}"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>Recycle</a></li>
```

Route:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('dashboard','DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');


Route::resource('category','CategoryController');
Route::get('catetgory/recycle','CategoryController@recycle')->name('category.recycle');
Route::post('catetgory/restore/{id}','CategoryController@restore')->name('category.restore');
Route::delete('catetgory/delete/{id}','CategoryController@delete')->name('category.delete');


Route::resource('brand','BrandController');
Route::get('brand/recycle','BrandController@recycle')->name('brand.recycle');
```

Controller:

```
public function recycle()
    {
        echo "check";
    }
```

When i run on my browser it gave 404|Not found error.

Comment: Show more content in the web.php, cause chances are its conflicting with some of the other previous routes

Comment: Could you include the output of `php artisan route:list` and your laravel log?

Comment: i gave the whole route. please check

Answer (score 1):

You have to invert the route declaration regarding the BrandController, i.e:

```
Route::get('brand/recycle','BrandController@recycle')->name('brand.recycle');
Route::resource('brand','BrandController');
```

That happens because the show route ('brand/{id}') is hiding your 'brand/recycle' route.

Comment: please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it's correct